# How to monitor an Akka actor in order to restart it after an Exception

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have an actor that could sometimes throw an `Exception` as this one:

```
import akka.actor._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class MonitorActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  context.system.scheduler.schedule(initialDelay = 0.seconds, interval = 3.seconds) {
    val r = Math.random()
    if (r > 0.8) throw new Exception
    else log info "missed"
  }

  def receive = {
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

I would like to restart it when the `Exception` occurs.
In order to do so, I have done this (as explained [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/supervision.html)):

```
val system = ActorSystem("scheduler")

val monitorActorProps = Props(classOf[MonitorActor])

val supervisor = BackoffSupervisor.props(
  Backoff.onFailure(
    monitorActorProps,
    childName = "error-actor",
    minBackoff = 1.seconds,
    maxBackoff = 12.seconds,
    randomFactor = 0.2
  ))

system.actorOf(supervisor, name = "echoSupervisor")
```

But when the exception is thrown the actor is not restarted. (It behaves in the same way if I use `onStop` instead of `onFailure`).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This actor seems to be a top-level actor which you cannot supervise unless you implement a [SupervisorStrategyConfigurator](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.2/?_ga=1.138322672.1948216317.1459366732#akka.actor.SupervisorStrategyConfigurator) as stated [on the guide on top-level supervisors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/general/supervision.html#The_Top-Level_Supervisors).

However, you're free to create an actor using BackoffSupervisor inside an actor which could be a top-level one.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your response, if I do the same thing inside a non top-level actor (i.e. I start an actor that start the supervisor), I don't get any difference.